# Парсинг вложенного JSON в Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Такая проблема,на вход получаю JSON такого вида

```
data: {
2416: {
id: 2416,
title: "",
parent_id: 0,
manual_url: "",
border: 0,
logos: [],
icon_src: null,
category_id: 80253,
top_category_id: 80253,
target_blank: 0,
banner_mobile_src: "",
on_subdomain: 0,
is_portal: false,
banner_href: "",
banner_src: "g",
children: {
one: [],
two: [],
three: []
},
popular_categories: [],
outer_link: false
},
3361: {
id: 3361,
title: "",
parent_id: 0,
manual_url: "",
border: 0,
logos: [
```

Моя цель, получить все категории, но добраться могу только до основных.
Дочерние категории, которые находятся в `children`: `one,two,three`, до них добраться не могу. При этом, что у этих категорий имеются еще свои дочерние категории.

Как циклом пройтись по всем категориям в JSON?

Пока у меня только точечно получить `children.one` из одного `id`. Вот так:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import io


url = "https://common-api.rozetka.com.ua/v2/fat-menu/full?front-type=xl&lang=ru"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json().get('data')


df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(data,
                       record_path=['2416', ['children','one']],


                       meta=[ ['2416', 'id'], ['2416', 'title']]) for d in data.values()], ignore_index=True)



print(df)
```

С соответствующим результатом:

```
        id                          title  ...  2416.id             2416.title
0     2423                       Ноутбуки  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
1     2472  Аксессуары для ноутбуков и ПК  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
2     2570                       Планшеты  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
3     2577         Аксессуары к планшетам  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
4    17942           Графические планшеты  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
..     ...                            ...  ...      ...                    ...
114   2570                       Планшеты  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
115   2577         Аксессуары к планшетам  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
116  17942           Графические планшеты  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
117   2675              Электронные книги  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
118  16890               Уцененные товары  ...     2416  Ноутбуки и компьютеры
```

Есть ли возможность собрать все категории (включая дочерние) сразу, а не точечно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, `json_normalize()` не умеет рекурсивно извлекать данные. Вам придется закодировать это самому. Т.е. нужно реализовать возможность рекурсивного прохождения по словарю и для каждого `child` вызывать `json_normalize()` и складывать результаты в список. В конце нужно объединить список фреймов при помощи `pd.concat()`.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.
А то я слишком долго с этим провозился.